# Prisma, Is it okay to not disconnect separately if I delete a row?

Tags: prisma

Is it okay to not disconnect separately if I delete a row??

```
data: {
                user: {
                    disconnect: {
                        id: 1,
                    },
                },
            },
```

Or do I have to do a separate disconnect before deleting a row like the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the referential action set on the relation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-actions

You can choose the behaviour you want when you delete a row and it has related data in other tables. You can choose to set the data to `null` or to delete the row it itself.